# Simplify Syntax

Tags: if-statement, simplify

This could be a basic question, however, I couldn't figure out how can I simplify this statement. I have a feeling that something's not right on this code.
Thank you.

```
        var a = string.Empty;
        if (File.Exists(a = Path.Combine(modelPath, "attributes", filename))) { }
        else
        {
            if (File.Exists(a = GetSaveAsAttribute(firmPath))) { }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < systemPaths.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (File.Exists(a = GetSaveAsAttribute(systemPaths[i])))
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   You can remove your **if**  by directly checking for another condition.


       var a = string.Empty;
       if (!(File.Exists(a = Path.Combine(modelPath, "attributes", filename)))) { 
              if (!(File.Exists(a = GetSaveAsAttribute(firmPath))) ){ 
                    for (int i = 0; i < systemPaths.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (File.Exists(a = GetSaveAsAttribute(systemPaths[i])))
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for this Diksha. I know this should be easy, wondrin why I'm turning blank on this one.

Comment: Is this the way you wanted ?